# SFML delaying time with clock doesn't work

Tags: c++, time, sfml

I am making an SFML framework, so I made a function for delaying time. I didn't use `sf::sleep` because it stops the whole application. So I used a clock but it doesn't work. Here's the code :

```
void FM::time::waitForSeconds(float seconds){

    bool finished = false;
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    sf::Clock clock;
    while (!finished) {

        elapsedTime += clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        if (elapsedTime >= seconds) {

            finished = true;
            clock.restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is no different from a sleep, except that it will consume a lot of Cpu and be slightly more accurate in how long it waits. Even if you fix the code this will also block the application.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Clock.php#a799feb6acb099b57b58d8d20984fce11), the function getElapsedTime() returns the time since the last call to `sf::Clock::restart` or since the creation of the object. This means that the value of the variable `elapsedTime` increases more rapidly than you think.

If you change the entire `while` loop to the following:

```
for(;clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() < seconds;); //Note the semi colon.
```

It should work.

I am assuming that when you say that it doesn't work, you mean that it finishes too "early".

Comment: Two problems here: First, this creates a busy loop, i.e. the CPU will run this loop as fast/often as possible, causing unnecessary overhead and also basically pausing the thread. Second, you shouldn't use `while()` this way, as this typically isn't intended and might be detected as a potential bug (plus I think compilers are even allowed to optimize it out; although don't quote me on that). If you really insist on implementing such a loop, use `for(;condition;);` instead.

Comment: I assumed OP for some reason wanted a busy loop. Good point on the use of a for-loop instead. I've edited my answer accordingly.